# xsl copy of subelement section using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, copy

I am trying to use an XSLT to achieve below; Keep only the first header and then all the "Detail" elements - everything under "Order". I tried several mixes of xsl copy; what i have tried is pasted below as well.

Input:

```
<Root>
<Order>
    <Header>
        <H1>abc</H1>
        <H2>123</H2>
    </Header>
    <Details>
        <Detail>
            <val1>test1</val1>
            <OrderId>111</OrderId>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <val1>test2</val1>
            <OrderId>112</OrderId>
        </Detail>
    </Details>
</Order>
<Order>
    <Header>
        <H1>abc</H1>
        <H2>123</H2>
    </Header>
    <Details>
        <Detail>
            <val1>test3</val1>
            <OrderId>113</OrderId>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <val1>test4</val1>
            <OrderId>114</OrderId>
        </Detail>
    </Details>
</Order>
</Root>
```

Expected Output is

```
<Order>
<Header>
    <H1>abc</H1>
    <H2>123</H2>
</Header>
<Details>
    <Detail>
        <val1>test1</val1>
        <OrderId>111</OrderId>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <val1>test2</val1>
        <OrderId>112</OrderId>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <val1>test3</val1>
        <OrderId>113</OrderId>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <val1>test4</val1>
        <OrderId>114</OrderId>
    </Detail>
</Details>
</Order>
```

What I have tried is below. But it did not provide the expected results for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name(*[1])}">
     <xsl:copy-of select="*[1]/Header"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="Detail"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks
Faris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <Order>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Order[1]/Header"/>
        <Details>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Order/Details/Detail"/>
        </Details>
    </Order>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That was much easier version. :) Thanks and it worked!